# How does Youtube make this animation?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's a gif to describe it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GafPq.jpg. If this is a Javascript animation, is there any broad tips in Javascript that I could follow to make this possible?

Comment: yes, that could be a gif, it could be Javascript, it could even be CSS

Comment: It can be simple CSS transition.

Comment: didn't think about that thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a CodePen that does this with a simple CSS transition and jQuery (have to add some code here so that SO will allow me to post links to codepen... so here's how I would structure the html!):

```
<div class="container">
   <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="click me"/>
   <div class="underline">
       <div id="highlight"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEVeqW

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't get the javascript going!

Comment: Javascript is absolutely unnecessary here.

Comment: How would you do this with pure css? The only thing I can think of is nesting the animation inside the input element and using css - is that possible?